# struct.pack() Python unknown fields length to send through a socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, struct, pack

I am developing a TCP client with Python. My problem comes when I want to send the structure to the server, I use the method `struct.pack()` to send and `struct.unpack()` to receive. I have my own protocol over TCP, with some headers which I already know the length of them, but of course, I don't know the length of the body, How could I pack all the fields without knowing the length of the body?  Here is an example:

**Request to the server:**

```
pack('!BBBBHHII', P2P_h.version, P2P_h.ttl, P2P_h.msgType, P2P_h.reserved, P2P_h.sendPort, P2P_h.payloadLength, P2P_h.ipSrc, P2P_h.messageId)
```

**Response from the server:**

```
queryHit = unpack ("!BBBBHHII", queryResponse)
```

In those examples there are just the headers, I mean, the fields that I already know their length, how could I add the body field?

Comment: What's the type of the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python socket's `send` and `` `recv `` operate on strings.
By using pack, you're already transforming other kinds of types (integers, booleans...) into strings. 
Assuming your body is just raw binary data - a string, that is - you just need to concatenate the string you already have with it. Also, since the body is of variable length, you probably want to also send the body size in the message, so that you know what size to read in `recv`:

```
data=pack('!BBBBHHII', P2P_h.version, P2P_h.ttl, P2P_h.msgType, P2P_h.reserved, P2P_h.sendPort, P2P_h.payloadLength, P2P_h.ipSrc, P2P_h.messageId) #your current header
data+= pack("!I",len(body)) #assumes len(body) fits into a integer
data+= body #assumes body is a string
socket.send(data)
```

To receive, you do the reverse:

```
data= socket.recv( struct.calcsize('!BBBBHHII') )
P2P_h.version, P2P_h.ttl, P2P_h.msgType, P2P_h.reserved, P2P_h.sendPort, P2P_h.payloadLength, P2P_h.ipSrc, P2P_h.messageId= unpack('!BBBBHHII', data)
data= socket.recv( struct.calcsize("!I") )
body_size= unpack("!I", data)
body= socket.recv( body_size )
```

I separated the body size from the other fields for clarity, but you can combine them.

Comment: And how would be the unpack when I recive data from the server?

Comment: @AlvaroGarciadelaVilla you just `socket.recv` with the received size. You can use `struct.calcsize` to calculate the size you should ask to receive. See code on edit